# struts 2 json plugin throws error no result type is defined

Tags: json, struts2, jsonp

I am using struts 2 json plugin for using the autocomplete. I have write an action

in struts.xml

```
<package name="example" extends="json-default">

    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult"/>
    </result-types>

      <action name="searchIndustryaction"  class="com.sample.action.GetStartedAction"  method="searchIndustry">
        <result name="success" type="json"></result>
      </action>

    </package>
```

it shows error in the response when i see through the firebug

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Struts Problem Report</title>
    <style>
        pre {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Struts Problem Report</h2>
    <p>
    Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
    </p>


<div id="exception-info">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Messages</strong>:</td>
        <td>
                    <li>No result defined for action com.cpt.fundation.action.GetStartedAction and result input</li>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>File</strong>:</td>
        <td>file:/D:/eclipse-indigo/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Fundation/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Line number</strong>:</td>
        <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Column number</strong>:</td>
        <td>119</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>

        <div id="snippet">
        <hr />

                    <pre>    &lt;/result-types&gt;</pre>
                    <pre>    </pre>
                        <pre style="background:yellow">      &lt;action name=&quot;searchIndustryaction&quot;  class=&quot;com.cpt.fundation.action.GetStartedAction&quot;  method=&quot;searchIndustry&quot;<span style="background:red">&gt;</span></pre>
                    <pre>       &lt;result name=&quot;success&quot; type=&quot;json&quot;&gt;&lt;/result&gt;</pre>
                    <pre>      &lt;/action&gt;</pre>
        </div>

<div id="stacktraces">
<hr />
<h3>Stacktraces</h3>
<div class="stacktrace" style="padding-left: 0em">
    <strong>No result defined for action com.cpt.fundation.action.GetStartedAction and result input - action - file:/D:/eclipse-indigo/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Fundation/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:70:119</strong>
    <div>
    <pre>
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:350)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:422)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    </pre>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
<hr />
<p>
You are seeing this page because development mode is enabled.  Development mode, or devMode, enables extra
debugging behaviors and reports to assist developers.  To disable this mode, set:
<pre>
  struts.devMode=false
</pre>
in your <code>WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties</code> file.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <result name="success" type="json">You need to specify result here</result>

  you did not specify any thing as result
```

Comment: this is json which result i need to specify

Comment: in action class you kept the result in a variable.is it correct?

Comment: you need to specify that variable name here.did you do that

Comment: i have included the variable like <param name="root">industry</param> i have getter and setter for industry in my action but  same issue is coming

Comment: did you checked in the action class weather the value is setting or not

Comment: can u show that code.i think you are getting some exception before that breakpoint

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25194/discussion-between-psr-and-jackyesind)

Comment: i canot continue in chat here chat is blocked

Comment: @PSR You don't need to specify a result if you're serializing from the root.

Comment: without specifying how it will know the name of variable

Comment: @PSR By default the action will be serialized, just like non-JSON results. You *may* specify the root (and several other things), but it is not *required* that you do so. Plus it's not the problem here anyway, as evidenced by the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a validation or type conversion exception, so it looks for the `"input"` result.

Fix the validation/type conversion exception.

Comment: i have skip the validation but i got error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult

Comment: @jackyesind Then you are not properly deploying the JSON plugin or one of its dependencies.

Comment: I have included the struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar file in lib folder and add the jar to the buildpath

Comment: @jackyesind Neat. However, it is not being deployed properly if that's the error you're getting. Not sure why you're defining a different json result type anyway, noting that the googlecode project hasn't seen a change in four years... why not use the official S2 plugin?

Comment: How would i do with s2 plugin. I need autocomplete. I am using jQuery ui version 10.

Comment: @jackyesind ... The same way.

Comment: when i am using struts2jquery plugin i got error like this javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/getStarted.jsp(119,9) The sj:autocompleter tag declares that it accepts dynamic attributes but does not implement the required interface
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:422)

Comment: @jackyesind I said the json, not the jquery plugin, although that's another option.

Comment: dave can u help me to resolve the The sj:autocompleter tag declares that it accepts dynamic attributes but does not implement the required interface. I have `<sj:autocompleter name="industrySearch" id="industrySearch" list="%{industryList}"/>` and have getter setter in action for industryList. and set thevalue in excute method

Comment: I am trying with struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar still i am getting error. Can u help me how to redeploy