# No result defined for action <class> and result input

Tags: java, json, struts2, actionresult, struts2-interceptors

**Here is my `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<package name="ajax" extends="json-default" >
    <action name="loadcity"  method="loadcity" class="roseindia.action.user.RegisterUser" >
        <result  type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

When I am calling `loadcity.action` I am getting following error

```
No result defined for action roseindia.action.user.RegisterUser and result input
```

**Here is my action method:**

```
public String loadcity()
{ 
    country=request.getParameter("country");
  
    cityList=  dao.loadcity(country);
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all your `srtuts.xml` file is not completely defining the result type which should be render on the response of you action execution .`result` tag plays the role of a view in the Struts2 MVC framework. The action is responsible for executing the business logic. The next step after executing the business logic is to display the view using the  tag.
Here you can do one thing

```
<package name="ajax" extends="json-default" >
    <action name="loadcity"  method="loadcity" class="roseindia.action.user.RegisterUser" >
        <result name="input" type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1):

`INPUT` result is returned by the [`workflow` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/default-workflow-interceptor.html) if your action has errors. These errors might be encountered by interceptors from the stack before your action is executed. For example, it could be validation errors when  the validation is performed because you have a [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) on the stack.

You should add an `INPUT` result to the action configuration. If you making Ajax request and expect JSON response then you can return an `INPUT` result of type `"json"`, where you can add errors and messages. You can also adjust a status code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `XML` node `result` should have an attribute `name` with the value of `"input"` as this is what you are returning.

So your struts.xml should look:

```
<package name="ajax" extends="json-default" >
    <action name="loadcity"  method="loadcity" class="roseindia.action.user.RegisterUser" >
        <result name="input" type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

**edited:**

Another error could be:

> You are getting a validation or type conversion exception, so it looks
>   for the "input" result.
>
> Fix the validation/type conversion exception.

source: [struts 2 json plugin throws error no result type is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103962/struts-2-json-plugin-throws-error-no-result-type-is-defined/15104137#15104137)

Comment: can you try naming that result to "input" ?

Comment: by the way... @user1773207 does this call have any validation? maybe it's failing at some point...

Comment: yes, It is working now thanks a lot but now it is giving error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/xwork/StringUtils

Comment: You have a missing jar on your build... please review.

Comment: @user1773207 You are probably mixing library versions; use only the versions defined by the project dependencies (i.e., you should be using Maven or its equivalent).